# Spring 5+Glassfish 4.1+ hibernate 5 : AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getSchema

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, glassfish-4

we are upgrading an application and I'm really stuck for days on the error below when trying to deploy the application on glassfish 4.1.1

Environment :

```
        Java 8
        DB1: Oracle 11g DB (ojdbc6.jar)
        DB2: Informix DB
        Hibernate Core : 5.2.8.Final
        Hibernate Search : 5.7.0.Final
        Spring 5.0.0
        Atomikos 4.0.4 (for transaction management)
```

Hibernate Search failed with the following error :

`ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.hibernate.search.exception.SearchException: HSEARCH000222: The SearchFactory was not initialized`

But when I look at the server instance log, the root cause is in the stack trace below :

```
[2017-03-04T16:47:44.366-0500] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [jdbc.ex_connection_holder] 
[javax.enterprise.resource.resourceadapter.com.sun.gjc.spi] [tid: _ThreadID=56 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1488664064366] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  RAR9008 : Exception while invoking method on Connection object. Exception : {0}
javax.resource.ResourceException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at com.sun.gjc.util.MethodExecutor.invokeMethod(MethodExecutor.java:244)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.jdbc40.ConnectionHolder40.getSchema(ConnectionHolder40.java:609)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.DefaultSchemaNameResolver$SchemaNameResolverJava17Delegate.resolveSchemaName(DefaultSchemaNameResolver.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.DefaultSchemaNameResolver.resolveSchemaName(DefaultSchemaNameResolver.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.determineCurrentSchemaName(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentImpl.<init>(JdbcEnvironmentImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:217)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:847)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:874)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:135)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:856)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5394)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:743)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5963)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:747)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2286)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1932)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)  
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.gjc.util.MethodExecutor.invokeMethod(MethodExecutor.java:238)
    ... 130 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.getSchema()Ljava/lang/String;
    ... 135 more
]]
```

These are all classes of my configuration :

```
@Configuration
@Import({AtomikosJtaConfig.class, Db1DatabaseConfig.class, Db2DatabaseConfig.class})
public class DatabaseConfig {
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AtomikosJtaConfig {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AtomikosJtaConfig.class.getSimpleName());

    @Bean(name = "atomikosUserTransaction")
    public UserTransaction atomikosUserTransaction()  {
        UserTransactionImp userTransactionImp = new UserTransactionImp();
        try {
            userTransactionImp.setTransactionTimeout(240);
        } catch (SystemException e) {
            log.debug(" Failed to set atomikos user transaction timeout. Caught {} ", e);
            throw new AtomikosConfigException(" Failed to set atomikos user transaction timeout. Caught {} ", e);
        }
        return userTransactionImp;
    }

    @Bean(name = "atomikosTransactionManager", initMethod = "init", destroyMethod = "close")
    public TransactionManager atomikosTransactionManager()  {
        UserTransactionManager userTransactionManager = new UserTransactionManager();
        userTransactionManager.setForceShutdown(true);
        userTransactionManager.setStartupTransactionService(false);
        return userTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    @DependsOn({ "atomikosUserTransaction", "atomikosTransactionManager" })
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JtaTransactionManager(atomikosUserTransaction(), atomikosTransactionManager());
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@DependsOn("transactionManager")
@EnableJpaRepositories( 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "db1EntityManagerFactory"
)
@ComponentScan("xx.xxx.xxx.db1")
public class Db1DatabaseConfig extends BaseDatabaseConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db1DataSource")
    public DataSource db1DataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        return dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/db1DB");
    }

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db1EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db1EntityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("xx.xxx.xxx.db1.entity");
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("db1PU");
        entityManagerFactory.setJtaDataSource(db1DataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(db1JpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaAdditionalProperties());
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean("fullTextEntityManager")
    public FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager() throws InterruptedException {
        return Search.getFullTextEntityManager(db1EntityManagerFactory().getObject().createEntityManager());
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor()  {
        return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor()  {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@DependsOn("transactionManager")
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "db2EntityManagerFactory"
)
@ComponentScan("xx.xxx.xxx.db2")
public class Db2DatabaseConfig  extends BaseDatabaseConfig {

    @Primary
    @Bean(name = "db2DataSource")
    public DataSource db2DataSource() {
        JndiDataSourceLookup dsLookup = new JndiDataSourceLookup();
        dsLookup.setResourceRef(true);
        return dsLookup.getDataSource("jdbc/db2DB");
    }

    @Bean(name = "db2EntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean db2EntityManagerFactory()  {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("xx.xxxdb2.entity");
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("db2PU");
        entityManagerFactory.setJtaDataSource(db2DataSource());
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceProvider(new HibernatePersistenceProvider());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(db2JpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(jpaPropertiesMap());
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor()  {
        return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor()  {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

---

```
public abstract class BaseDatabaseConfig {

    protected Map<String, Object> jpaPropertiesMap() {
        HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.transaction.jta.platform","com.atomikos.icatch.jta.hibernate4.AtomikosPlatform");
        properties.put("javax.persistence.transactionType","JTA");
        properties.put("hibernate.search.autoregister_listeners","false");
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.handling_mode","DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_AFTER_TRANSACTION");
        properties.put("hibernate.connection.release_mode","on_close");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache","false");
        return properties;
    }

    protected JpaVendorAdapter db2JpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.INFORMIX);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }

    protected JpaVendorAdapter db1JpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }
```

JNDI resources (jdbc/db1DB and jdbc/db2DB) have been created successfully in Glassfish and are bind to connection pools (poolDB1 and poolDB2). Ping queries work. Oracle driver (ojdbc6.jar) and informix have been dropped in glassfish/domains/zzzz/lib and not package in the application (mark as provided im pom.xml)

I don't see what's wrong in my configuration.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.